# Unable to load image if there is a space in path or name file Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with a load dynamically an Asset image.

I have an image and I'm trying to load with:

```
new AssetImage(img_path)
```

The img_path is:

> /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/test.jpg

And it return:

> (27161): Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset:
>   /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/test.jpg

If i try to move my file for example in

> /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/test.jpg

It works.

But not if I change name of my file with space for example:

> /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/test with space.jpg

So I guess that It can be a problem with a space in path.

How can I solve this?

Comment: How did you register it in `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: No because I have to show the image when the user load, so I can't register.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/test.jpg` doesn't look like an `AssetImage`. You probably want to use a `FileImage` instead.

Comment: Yeah! thankyou Gunter! With FileImage it Work.

Comment: Image.file(
                                        File('/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/test.jpg'),
                                      ),

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume this is what you actually want

```
new FileImage(
    new File('/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/test.jpg')
)
```

See also https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/FileImage-class.html

Comment: Thank you so much it work.
Could you explain, in your reply, what is the difference beetween AssetImage and FileImage?

Comment: Assets are resources embedded in the APK used to install the application. You need to register such assets in `pubspec.yaml` for them to be added to the APK. Assets are embedded in the installed app and therefore not directly available as files on the devices storage. AssetBundle allows you to read from assets (AssetImage uses that). `ImageFile` is for image files available on the devices storage as normal files. https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/

Comment: Didn't work for me. Getting this message: 
Exception was thrown: type 'FileImage' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Comment: Use `Image.file(...)` instead.

Comment: I am using it like this: 
Container(
                            height: 200.0,
                            child: Image.file(
                            loadImageFromFile(imageController.text),
                            ),
                          )

Comment: loadImageFromFile(String imgPath) {
    return FileImage(
      File(imgPath),
    );
  }

Comment: In this case `loadImageFromFile` should look like `loadImageFromFile(String imgPath) { return File(imgPath); }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the image as a `Widget`, `FileImage()` doesn't work so you need to use `Image.file()` like this:

```
...

Image.file(File('/storage/emulated/0/lilop_app/native_screenshot-20211107163229.png'), width: 100),

...
```