# Unable to load asset at first build but they load at hot-restart Flutter

Tags: flutter

When I first launch the app eight on simulator or real device, I get this error:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
flutter: Unable to load asset: assets/New alert button.png
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
flutter: <asynchronous suspension>
flutter: #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:484:44)
flutter: #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:469:14)
flutter: #3      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:17)
flutter: #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:160:22)
flutter: #5      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:325:84)
flutter: (elided 13 frames from package dart:async)
flutter:
flutter: Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/New alert button.png")
flutter: Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#3cb5b(), name: "assets/New alert
flutter:   button.png", scale: 1.0)
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: assets/New route button.png
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: assets/Center map button.png
```

Reading other posts related to the problem (different solutions suggested different ways) I I tried different indentations so I tried both :

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
  - assets/
```

and

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
```

but nothing changed. If I perform a hot-restart assets load correctly.
One other problem I have, and maybe a hint to the real underlying problem, is that if I drag and drop images into the asset folder from IDE I get an error:

[image]

This is one button using the assets:

```
IconButton(
                        icon: Image.asset('assets/Center map button.png'),
                        iconSize: 60,
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('Center map button pressed');
                          _mapController.move(userLocation, 16);
                        }),
```

Canyon spot what am I doing wrong?
As always many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Kill your app and uninstall from your device.
Then try this:
1. `flutter pub get` 
 2. `flutter clean`

Comment: @Mateen Tried it adit didn't solve it. I then deleted the folder and created it again, and at least now it accepts drag'n bro files. Still it doesn't load them at first build. I created those files with Adobe Illustratore, can it be has anything to do with the problem? I see `following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:` in the exeption

Comment: Isn't it because your image path contains space? [Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47705) they talked about it and gave some solutions.(on the other mentioned issues)

Comment: @NoobN3rd That was it indeed, thanks. I camel cased them and it works. I see that this problem is related to the version I'm using at the moment nut it should be solved for newer versions. Still a good idea to camel case everything..

Comment: If you wanna make it an answer I'll be glad to accept it ;)

Comment: I searched and found a duplicate question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295714/unable-to-load-image-if-there-is-a-space-in-path-or-name-file-flutter). for paths if I make no mistake I usually see underscore is chosen as the separator.

Comment: In my case I have need the file name not be named as I was before fore other parts of the app, camel cased or underscored names are fine for buttons and alike, but I actually use the file name both to choose the image to display and as the title fro display it, so I might just reformat the string to show what I need.. I'll install Catalina and the newer stable Flutter version and see if that's been solved and rethink the business login accordingly if necessary, as in iOS It worked the way it is now( naming wise). Thank you very much.

Comment: is there any answer to this question?

Comment: HI, actually it was the naming of the file, use  camel case or snake case, my problem was the space in the file name `Center map button`. No answer was provided to the question but actually solved in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments the problem was with file naming `Center map button` as space separation is not accepted. By using either camel casing `centerMapButton` or  snake casing `center_map_button` the problem is solved.